# UITableViewController as data entry screen (iOS, Swift) a la Calendar app "New Event" screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, unwind-segue, data-entry

My app tracks events. Users can create new events or join existing ones. Events have Title, Location, Start Date, optional End Date, etc.

I have a `UITableViewController` to show the list of events, bog standard with one custom cell.

My data entry screen (see Image 2) to create an event is also a `UITableViewController`, similar to the Apple iOS Calendar app's "New Event" screen (see Image 1). I created multiple Prototype Cells (one with a `UITextField`, another with a `UIDatePicker`, another with a `UICollectionView`, etc.). The screen, as such, is working fine, but...

I'm trying to create an unwind segue like in [this tutorial from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1) in the section "Create an Unwind Segue". Step 7 - no problem. Step 8 - eek!

In the tutorial, there are simple controls to collect the data, create a "Meal", add it to the array of meals and return to the list of Meals. But, I have a UITableViewController.

**I have no idea how to collect the data in order to create my Event, add it to the array, etc.**

Do I need to redesign my UI without using a `UITableViewController`? It seems like the perfect UI for this scenario.

[image: iOS Calendar App New Event screen]
[image: My app data entry screen]

Comment: I suggest you use [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) if you are not already. It makes life much simpler.

Comment: Woah, that's some funky looking code. Is it swift?

Comment: It is. It's made possible with operator overloading.

Comment: Cool. But...I'm looking at his example, the one called "Native iOS Event Form".... there's a cancel button, but not a Save button. So, I still don't know how to get the data out of the form to save it.

Comment: There is a section in the README file dedicated to that: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#getting-row-values

Comment: I was searching for "save" and "saving", not "getting". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Delegates to get the data from the Table xib to whichever controller you want,Hope this helps

1.Add this method on top of your xib's viewcontroller file

```
protocol ViewModelDelegate
{
    func sendValue(from PassData: String?)

}

class XibViewController: UITableViewCell {

    var controller:HomeViewController()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        controller.delegate = self

    }

    //call this method on any button action or save 
    controller.sendValue(from PassData:String?)




}
```

2. Create a function where you want to fetch all data into viewcontroller.

   ```
       class:HomeViewController:UITableViewController
       {
       override func viewDidLoad()
       {

        super.viewDidLoad()

       }

       func sendValue(from PassData:String?)
       {
          //code to get the data from picker or textfield

       }   
       }
   ```